# Analyze the Pointwise and Uniform Convergence of: $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin{nx}}{n^3}, x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Not understanding the concept well, I am trying to determint the pointwise and uniform convergence of the following sequence of function:

$$f_n(x) = \frac{\sin{nx}}{n^3}, x \in \mathbb{R}$$

The only part I understand so far is that I need $\lim_{x\to\infty}{f_n(x)}$ in which I have determined that (if I am correct):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{f_n(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{\sin{nx}}{n^3}} = 0$$

Where do i go from here?

Comment: It's not the function that converges but the sequence of function. Do you want to study the sequence or the series ?

Comment: @Atmos I believe it's the sequence.

Comment: pointwise convergence is okey it also converges to zero function uniformly

Comment: $\left|\sin\right|\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what you wrote I think that you want to study the sequence $\left(f_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. With what you wrote, you have proved that the sequence $\left(f_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converge pointwisely on $\mathbb{R}$ to the function $ \ f: x \mapsto 0$. Now you need to prove the following statement for proving that it converges uniformly :
$$
\left\|f_n-f\right\|_{\infty,\mathbb{R}} \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
$$
Here $f=0$ and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\left|f_n\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)\right|=\left|\frac{\sin\left(nx\right)}{n^3} \right|\leq \frac{1}{n^3}
$$
It is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so in particular for the upper bound 
$$
\left\|f_n-f\right\|_{\infty, \mathbb{R}}\leq \frac{1}{n^3}
$$
Hence

> $$
> \left\|f_n-f\right\|_{\infty,\mathbb{R}} \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
> $$
>   The convergence is hence uniform.

Comment: So basically I would have to find an upper limit that applies for all $x$?

Comment: Yes and that does not depend on $x$. If it tends to $0$, hence the convergence is uniform. Be careful, if $f$ was for example $-4x$ then you should have studied the upperbound of $\displaystyle x \mapsto \left|f_n(x)-4x\right|$.

Comment: Would it be a similar solution for $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin{(nx)}}{\sqrt{n}}$?

Comment: If you are studying the sequence, yes.

Comment: So if I am correct it would be almost the same solution just the difference being the original function?

Comment: Yes, you can put any sequence $a_n$ that tends to $0$ the sequence $f_n(x)=a_n sin(nx)$ will converge uniformly to $0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also, for the function $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+nx^2}$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ where it only converges pointwise for $1 \le x \le \infty$ and since $|f_n(x) - f(x)| = f_n(x)$ and it's limit varies, how do I know exactly if it converges uniformly or not?

Comment: Why $\left[1,+\infty \right[$ ?

Comment: My mistake. But that would mean that it converges for $x = 1$ and for $x = 0$?

Comment: Yes but for $x=1$ it converges to $0$ while for $x=0$ it converges to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, the deciding factor in uniform convergence is whether the "rate" of convergence of $f_n(x)$ to its limit is the same for all $x$.

A counterexample: let $f_n(x)=x/n$. The functions $f_n$ converge to $0$ pointwise. However, the time you have to wait for $f_n(x)$ to get within $0.01$ of $0$ depends on $x$. For example, when $x=3$, then the smallest $n$ such that $|f_n(x)|<0.01$ is $n=300$, while for $x=30$, the smallest such $n$ is $n=3000$. As $x$ gets further from $0$, the required $n$ to get $f_n(x)$ within $0.01$ of $0$ gets arbitrarily large, which means $f_n$ does not converge uniformly.

Back to your problem. The function $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)/n^3$ is more complicated, so given $\epsilon$, we cannot find the exact smallest $n$ for which $|f_n(x)|<\epsilon$. However, all we need to do is note that $|\sin nx|\le 1$ always, so that $|f_n(x)|\le 1/n^3$. Note that this bound does not depend on $x$; it gives us a guarantee that after $n$ is large enough, $f_n(x)$ will be close to $0$ for *all* $x$. Therefore, $f_n$ does indeed converge uniformly.